# Numbering of tables and figures misplaced with Hungarian and Greek Babel

Tags: tables, babel, babel-greek

When loading Hungarian and Greek (with `provide+=*`) with babel, I encounter the effect that in the caption the position of the table numbering and the label are reverted, i.e. it is no longer "Table 1", but "1. Table". The same happens with figures using `\includegraphics`.

It only happens in this specific combination of languages. If I leave out Hungarian, it's fine, if I leave out the `provide+=*` option for Greek, it's fine. However, for my bigger setup I depend on the `provide+=*` option for Greek. (I have a total of 16 languages in the document, which all work fine. It is just this tiny problem that keeps me from finally implementing babel.)

It took me a while to narrow it down to this combination, but I finally managed to come up with an MWE that reproduces the issue. It occurs compiling with both xelatex and lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hungarian,greek,provide+=*,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{\label{tab:table1}Example Table}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
        cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
        cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Am I missing an option for one of the languages? How can I get the numbering back to its correct position?

Comment: If the secondary languages are used in just a few words or some sentences, try *not* declaring them explicitly. Depending on your needs it might work. I’ve opened and issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/203 .

Comment: I’ve managed to fix it in the release I’d planned for today, which I’ve just uploaded to CTAN. It should be available in 1-2 days.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot for the fast fix, @JavierBezos! I have an equally big amount of content for all languages, so I need to declare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not confirm that greek is related. As soon as one loads hungarian it changes the caption as hungarian provides a template.

Imho you have currently two options to reset the caption:

- with the caption package (after babel):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
hungarian,
provide+=*,
english
]{babel}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple} %original doesn't work

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Example Table}
    

    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
        cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
        cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\selectlanguage{hungarian}

\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{Example Table}
    

    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
        cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
        cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

xxx
\end{document}
```

Or by resetting the template (this then must be done also for figure):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
hungarian,
provide+=*,
english
]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{hungarian}{table.template}{[[table]]\nobreakspace[table]}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The caption package solution works great for me. And my apologies to greek!